# Xubuntu 16 Plymouthd crashes on every boot

Tags: ubuntu, xubuntu, plymouth

I get three crash errors with every boot-up. This is the first one.

[image]

I have tried

```
sudo chown -R $USER: /lib/plumouth
```

and

```
audo apt-get install plumouth-x11
```

and

```
dpkg-reconfigure Plymouth
```

But none of these have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is well-known. There is even a bug report.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/1542000

Decides whoever can.

Try

`sudo chown -R : /sbin/plymouthd`

One helps, one does not. I was helped to remove `plymouth`and installed plymouth using Synaptic, and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo chown -R : /sbin/plymouthd
```

This worked for my Dell i5 7000 laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 Mate DE.

Comment: Are you sure this does something? I believe that this doesn’t do anything.  What do you think it does?